# How can I return the highest "valued" element -- per "name" -- in an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I've read a lot of posts about finding the highest-valued objects in arrays using max and max_by, but my situation is another level deeper, and I can't find any references on how to do it.

I have an experimental Rails app in which I am attempting to convert a legacy .NET/SQL application. The (simplified) model looks like `Overlay -> Calibration <- Parameter`. In a single data set, I will have, say, 20K Calibrations, but about 3,000-4,000 of these are versioned duplicates by Parameter name, and I need only the highest-versioned Parameter by each name. Further complicating matters is that the version lives on the Overlay. (I know this seems crazy, but this models our reality.)

In pure SQL, we add the following to a query to create a virtual table:

```
n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parameters.Designation ORDER BY Overlays.Version DESC)
```

And then select the entries where `n = 1`.

I can order the array like this:

```
ordered_calibrations = mainline_calibrations.sort do |e, f|
  [f.parameter.Designation, f.overlay.Version] <=> [e.parameter.Designation, e.overlay.Version] || 1
end
```

I get this kind of result:

```
C_SCR_trc_NH3SensCln_SCRT1_Thd  160
C_SCR_trc_NH3SensCln_SCRT1_Thd  87
C_SCR_trc_NH3Sen_DewPtHiThd_Tbl 310
C_SCR_trc_NH3Sen_DewPtHiThd_Tbl 160
C_SCR_trc_NH3Sen_DewPtHiThd_Tbl 87
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way, using Ruby's Enumerable built-in methods, to loop over the sorted array, and only return the highest-versioned elements per name. HUGE bonus points if I could feed an integer to this method's block, and only return the highest-versioned elements UP TO that version number ("160" would return just the second and fourth entries, above).

The alternative to this is that I could somehow implement the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` in ActiveRecord, but that seems much more difficult to try. And, of course, I could write code to deal with this, but I'm quite certain it would be orders of magnitude slower than figuring out the right Enumerable function, if it exists.

(Also, to be clear, it's trivial to do .find_by_sql() and create the same result set as in the legacy application -- it's even fast -- but I'm trying to drag all the related objects along for the ride, which you really can't do with that method.)

Comment: Please help us to answer your query by writing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you say "Parameter name" are you talking about `Parameters.Designation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that doing this in the database isn't a better option, but since I'm unfamiliar with SQL Server I'll give you a Ruby answer.

I'm assuming that when you say "Parameter name" you're talking about the `Parameters.Designation` column, since that's the one in your examples.

One straightforward way you can do this is with [`Enumerable#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), which is available in Ruby 2.2+. `slice_when` is good when you want to slice an array "between" values that are different in some way. For example:

```
[ { id: 1, name: "foo" }, { id: 2, name: "foo" }, { id: 3, name: "bar" } ]
  .slice_when {|a,b| a[:name] != b[:name] }
# => [ [ { id: 1, name: "foo" }, { id: 2, name: "foo" } ],
#      [ { id: 3, name: "bar" } ]
#    ]
```

You've already sorted your collection, so to slice it you just need to do this:

```
calibrations_by_designation = ordered_calibrations.slice_when do |a, b|
  a.parameter.Designation != b.parameter.Designation
end
```

Now `calibrations_by_designation` is an array of arrays, each of which is sorted from greatest `Overlay.Version` to least. The final step, then, is to get the first element in each of those arrays:

```
highest_version_calibrations = calibrations_by_designation.map(&:first)
```

Comment: Getting the versions equal to or less than a particular version number is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem now, but .slice_when() was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: A note on speed. My .find_by_sql() method, which uses the database engine to sort all of this out, takes 2 seconds for the AR part, and 3.5 seconds for the view. Using my very-complicated AR finder and sorting out the results with the solution above takes 4 seconds for the AR part, and 16 seconds for the view. Looks like pulling all the associated things along for the ride may just be untenable.